# Spring Kafka single producer for multiple topics

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I want to use a single producer for writing JSON objects to multiple topics.

The following code is doing what I want but it feels wrong to use the `setDefaultTopic()` method to tell the `KafkaTemplate` to which topic it should send the message.

If I use the `send(String topic, ? payload)` method than the `StringJsonMessageConverter` won't work.

My Producer:

```
public class MyProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, ?> kafka;

    public void send(String topic, Message<?> message) {
        kafka.setDefaultTopic(topic);
        kafka.send(message);
    }
}
```

And my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ...

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());

        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to this ...

Producer:

```
public void send(Message<?> message) {
    kafka.send(message);
}
```

In my controller (where I create the message objects);

```
MessageHeaders headers = new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "topicName"));
GenericMessage<NewsRequest> genericMessage = new GenericMessage<>(payload, headers);
producer.send(genericMessage);
```

The MessageHeaders object will still contain the id and timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `send(Message<?>)` variant, the message converter expects the topic to be in a message header...

```
String topic = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, String.class);
```

If you can determine the topic some other way, you need to create a custom converter.

Changing the default topic is not thread-safe.

Comment: It's working. Thank you! I didn't know about the `KafkaHeaders` class and the `MessageHeaders` class doesn't provide a static field for the topic.

Comment: @GaryRussell Can I use this with different value serializers?

Comment: It's generally best to ask a new question rather than comment on 2 year old answers. I am not sure what you are asking, but the recent 2.3 version [now has a delegating serializer/deserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#delegating-serialization) allowing the use of different serializers in the same producer, based on a message header. If that's not what you are asking, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `StringJsonMessageConverter` manually before calling template:

```
ProducerRecord<?, ?> producerRecord = kafka.getMessageConverter().fromMessage(message, topic);
kafka.send(producerRecord);
```

Comment: That is performed by the template internally; see my answer.